# Split json data to columns in excel

Tags: excel

I have a column with JSON data inside. The fields inside are not consistent so I cannot use text-to-column

```
{'gender': 'Female', 'nationality': 'ESP', 'document_type': 'passport', 'date_of_expiry': '2021-01-25', 'issuing_country': 'ESP'}

{'document_type': 'driving_licence', 'date_of_expiry': '2056-03-07', 'issuing_country': 'GRC'}
```

How do I get this into columns such as gender, nationality, document_type etc.

Thanks

Comment: If you have [this Power Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-data-from-external-data-sources-power-query-be4330b3-5356-486c-a168-b68e9e616f5a), or [this Power Query](https://syntaxbytetutorials.com/import-json-data-in-excel-2016-or-2019-or-office-365-using-a-get-transform-query/), or use this online converter to go [JSON to CSV](https://json-csv.com/).

Answer (score 8):

Just to clarify, does one of the columns in your Excel spreadsheet contain JSON encoded data? If so, it is fairly easy to transform using PowerQuery.

Go to the sheet containing your data, and select **Data**, **From Table/Range** [image].

This should select the sheet as a Range of data for further transformation and load it into the PowerQuery Editor.

Click the Column header of the column that contains the JSON encoded data.  This will select the column. Right mouse click and select **Transform**, **JSON**

[image]

PowerQuery recognises that each cell contains a JSON Record and will convert the data to a Record.

[image]

Now you can choose which columns you would like to display in your table.  Here, I only want the one that has ObjectID.

[image]

Now you will have a column (or columns if you selected more than one) with the seperated data from the JSON Record.  You can use the **Choose Columns** or **Remove Columns** to from the main toolbar to further refine your view.

Once you are happy, just **Close and Load** to use the data to a new Excel Sheet.

PowerQuery is extremely powerful for this type of data manipulation and is well worth spending a little time to learn.

Comment: Thank you, old post, no feedback, no idea why, you gave just enough info that I was able to do what I wanted. +1 from me.